# Run a PHP file in an EC2 instance

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created an EC2 instance and use the command line interface to connect to it.

I created a HTML page in the /var/www/html for testing purpose. When I enter my public DNS (taken from my ec2 AWS console) in the Browser, my HTML content is successfully displayed.

I would like to host a PHP file in the EC2 instance which I want to run from java code. The PHP file is in the location "/opt/app/current".

When I enter the public DNS, it successfully displays the HTML page, but the PHP code is not present there nor has it run and updated my database.

I am not sure if I am missing any steps.

Comment: is php installed on your instance? some of them do not ship with it preinstalled. does your java code run?

Comment: I had installed php also using the below:sudo yum install php-mysql php php-xml php-mcrypt php-mbstring php-cli mysql httpd

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the document root from /var/www/html to /opt/app/current on main configuaration file of httpd service (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf -- for Amazon Linux, Redhat, Centos)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i had already the changed the DocumentRoot under the virtual host. I had removed the rest of the tags like ServerAdmin,ServerName,ErrorLog,CustomLog. Still it did not work, the html page was only getting displayed.

Comment: I have also changed: <Directory "/var/www/html">
 Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
 AllowOverride All
 Allow from all
</Directory> AllowOverride to All

Comment: I had restarted my httpd, finally now i am lead to the Amazon Linux AMI Testpage, instead of my html page. But not to my php page. I also tried changing the php.conf file(present in: etc/httpd/conf.d) pointing to my php page instead of index.php. Still it doesnt work

Comment: @abhirami: Can you please send your configuration file so that I can help you better

Answer (score 0):

Which server are you using? seems it is Apache first try to check if you Apache configuration is ok

https://www.maketecheasier.com/configure-apache-php-linux-server/

You can easily validate you config by using

```
apachectl configtest

apachectl -t
```

or even better:

```
apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS
```

After that you should be able to understand what is wrong, algo you need to check your apache logs probably there you can found more details